# Nested reshape from wide to long

Tags: r, reshape

I keep on getting all sort of error messages when trying to reshape an object into long direction. Toy data:

```
d <- structure(c(0.204, 0.036, 0.015, 0.013, 0.208, 0.037, 0.015, 
0.006, 0.186, 0.044, 0.016, 0.023, 0.251, 0.044, 0.02, 0.01, 
0.268, 0.04, 0.007, 0.007, 0.208, 0.062, 0.027, 0.036, 0.272, 
0.054, 0.006, 0.01, 0.274, 0.05, 0.011, 0.006, 0.28, 0.039, 0.007, 
0.019, 1.93, 0.345, 0.087, 0.094, 2.007, 0.341, 0.064, 0.061, 
1.733, 0.39, 0.131, 0.201, 0.094, 0.01, 0.004, 0, 0.096, 0.014, 
0, 0.001, 0.081, 0.016, 0.002, 0.016, 0.062, 0.007, 0.011, 0.001, 
0.07, 0.003, 0.005, 0.002, 0.043, 0.033, 0, 0.007, 0.081, 0.039, 
0.007, 0, 0.085, 0.033, 0.008, 0, 0.086, 0.023, 0.007, 0.007, 
0.083, 0.015, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.009, 0, 0, 0.049, 0.052, 0, 0.025, 
2.779, 0.203, 0.098, 0.016, 2.801, 0.242, 0.135, 0.01, 2.12, 
0.466, 0.177, 0.121, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), .Dim = c(12L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", 
    "3"), c("age_77", "age_78", "age_79", "age_80", "age_81", 
    "age_82", "age_83", "age_84", "age_85", "item", "k")))
```

Basically I have different ages, for which 3 items have been reported with four response categories each. I would like to obtain a long-shaped object with `colnames = age, item, k, proportion`, like this:

```
  structure(c(77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78,
78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
0.204, 0.036, 0.015, 0.013, 0.208, 0.037, 0.015, 0.006, 0.186, 
0.044, 0.016, 0.023, 0.251, 0.044, 0.02, 0.01, 0.268, 0.04, 0.007, 
0.007, 0.208, 0.062, 0.027, 0.036), .Dim = c(24L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", 
    "3", "0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", "3", "0", "1", "2", 
    "3"), c("age", "item", "k", "proportion")))
```

An example I tried:

```
reshape(as.data.frame(d), varying =1:9, sep = "_", direction = "long",
                        times = "k", idvar = "item")
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(ids, times[i],  :
```

duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Any clue where's my mistake? Thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: Can you please add expected output and any packages you use (`%>%`) is not base R

Comment: `reshape` requires a data.frame as input, but  `d` is a matrix. In addition, row names are not unique.

Comment: proportions are the values contained in the `age` colums

Comment: Try to remove row names of `d` using `row.names(d) <- NULL` before calling `as.data.frame(d)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `d` as provided by the OP is not a data.frame but a matrix which is causing the error:

```
str(d)
```

> ```
>  num [1:12, 1:11] 0.204 0.036 0.015 0.013 0.208 0.037 0.015 0.006 0.186 0.044 ...
>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   ..$ : chr [1:12] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
>   ..$ : chr [1:11] "age_77" "age_78" "age_79" "age_80" ...
> ```

In addition, the row numbers are not unique which causes an error as well when coercing `d` to data.frame.

With `data.table`, `d` can be coerced to a data.table object and reshaped from wide to long format using `melt()`. Finally, `age` is extracted from the column names and stored as integer values as requested by the OP.

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(d), measure.vars = patterns("^age_"),
     variable.name = "age", value.name = "proportion")[
  , age := as.integer(stringr::str_replace(age, "age_", ""))][]
```

> ```
>      item k age proportion
>   1:    1 0  77      0.204
>   2:    1 1  77      0.036
>   3:    1 2  77      0.015
>   4:    1 3  77      0.013
>   5:    2 0  77      0.208
>  ---                      
> 104:    2 3  85      0.010
> 105:    3 0  85      2.120
> 106:    3 1  85      0.466
> 107:    3 2  85      0.177
> 108:    3 3  85      0.121
> ```